# Send email to recipients with (varying) multiple attachments based on criteria in columns

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently trying to write a macro where it will email multiple attachments to recipients depending on whether each column has an **X** next to their name.
I have the email addresses in column **G** and 11 different report names ranging from columns **H:R**.

So far I've written a macro that will send an attachment (*Report 1*) if email recipients have an **X** in column **H**, but I'm unsure how to write a macro so it will search columns **H:R** for **X** and send the corresponding reports (i.e. If an email recipient has an **X** in column **H** and column **J** then I want them to receive both *Report 1* and *Report 3* in the same email).

Sorry if my explanation is difficult to interpret. 
Any help is much appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range


    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Contacts")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value) = "x" Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Report 1"
                .body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value
            'Link file path for attachment
                .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\smcelroy021218\Desktop\Email Macro Working.xlsm")
                .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The line ".Attachments.Add ("C:\...) is just a dummy file for testing btw. Ideally, I would like the macro to grab the attachment file paths from rows "H1:R1" - corresponding to the 11 different report columns.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where the file paths come from: in this example I'm picking them up from the first row of your sheet (so from H1:R1).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, c As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngAttach As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Contacts")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        Set rngAttach = cell.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 11)

        'EDIT: must have at least one attachment to create a mail
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
                          Application.Countif(rngAttach, "x") > 0 Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Report 1"
                .body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value

                'loop over H:R and check for "x"
                For Each c In rngAttach.Cells
                    If LCase(Trim(c.Value)) = "x" Then
                        'pick up the file path from the top row of the sheet
                        .Attachments.Add sh.Cells(1, c.Column).Value
                    End If
                Next c

                .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing

        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Haha beat me to it. Btw, he did mention in the comment that the paths are in `H1:R1`.

Comment: @L42 - I missed that, so lucky guess I suppose!

Comment: Wow! This is great, thank you so much.
Just a quick follow up, it doesn't seem to be picking up my file path ( I did move the filepath to H2:R2, as I now included headers) but I changed the code accordingly.
This probably seems like a real trivial question, but do I include the full file path into the cell? i.e. C:\Users\smcelroy021218\Desktop\Email Macro Working.xlsm
Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: To pick up from Row 2 you'd use: `.Attachments.Add sh.Cells(2, c.Column).Value`  Not sure I follow your question about how to include the full path.  If all of your attachments are in the same folder you could just put the file names in H2:R2 and use something like `.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\smcelroy021218\Desktop\" & sh.Cells(2, c.Column).Value`

Comment: Ahhh my apologies, silly mistake in the file path. Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi guys, sorry to bother. 
But emails are still created even if an "X" isn't in any of the rows. Do you know how I would stop this? 
Also, it appears that all the corresponding attachments are attached minus 1 (no matter what order the X's are in). I'm struggling to see what's causing this?
Thanks again.

Comment: See my edit for the "must have at least 1 attachment" fix.  It's not clear exactly what the other problem is - you need to be more specific about that.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tim.

For the second problem, if a person has, for example, 4 X's then only 3 reports are attached. This happens regardless on where the X's are, i.e. 2 people may have X's in completely different columns but they will still receive 1 less attachment than they should. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: EDIT: It's always the column with the first "X" for the person that isn't attached in the email, i.e. if a person should have Report 2, Report 4 and Report 5 attached, only Report 4 and 5 will be attached.

Comment: Make sure `rngAttach` is pointing to the correct range, and try stepping through the `For Each c In rngAttach` loop.

Comment: Bingo! Found the issue, I had to change cell.Offset(0 ,7) to cell.Offset(0, 0).

Once again, thanks so much for all your help, Tim, You're a true life saver!!